# Curly brace style in python logging

Tags: python-3.x, python-logging

First three paragraphs of [this section](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) state one might use {}-formatting for logging format string.

> If you are using {}-formatting (str.format()), you can use {attrname} as the placeholder in the format string.

However, it does not work.

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='[{asctime}] {message}')
logging.info('foo')
```

Prints,

```
[{asctime}] {message}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to declare your formatting style:

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='[{asctime}] {message}', style='{')
logging.info('test')
```

Works fine:

```
[2020-03-24 14:44:02,214] test
```